# gRPC: Is it possible to generate the server and client stubs to separate directories?

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, protobuf-net, grpc-java, grpc-go

I have been scouring the Internet to determine whether it is possible to generate the server and client stubs into separate directories?  I am able to generate the stubs into separate directories for each of the following languages, but cannot figure out how to separate the server from the client files for each language.  I'd appreciate your tips and advice.

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: I think you likely cannot. `protoc` uses folder structure to reflect package structure and, since client and server stubs represent the same package, they're in the same folder. What are you trying to do that requires this?

Comment: You can run it twice with 2 different destination directories and after each run delete the client and server stubs respectively.